Allow sorting of questions in the Staging Ground by creation date
At the moment, the only available sorting for questions is either by status or by last activity.

However, neither is stable enough so that on refresh you get (mostly) the same items. This makes it hard to look through items in a consistent manner.
For example, I might want to check the newly added items, or just go through the ones since I last checked the list. That is not possible without consistent ordering by creation date.

Note that as a workaround, you can use the search with the staging-ground:1 operator but this will give you different filters (e.g. you can't filter by the Staging Ground status in the search as far as I know).

@dan1st that is honestly even better. Keyboard shortcuts don't work in SG but they do in the search page. That makes going through the posts much easier. I only wish I could exclude graduated posts from the search. But that's probably a separate requirement. I can definitely live with them for now.

If that is really necessary, I guess a user script hiding SG posts by status could help ;)
